# Change Permissions of MSSQL Server generated files

Tags: sql-server, permissions, restore

I am routinely taking a BAK file and restoring it. As a result of this action, an MDF file is generated from it by MSSQL.

My problem is that after the detaching the database I need to be able to move the MDF file programmatically and the user that is going to do this needs to not be in the Administrators group or to be the Default SQL server account. Is it possible to configure MSSQL server to that when it creates an MDF file such as this the permissions of the file include a group of my own arbitrary choosing?

It seems logical that this an MSSQL server setting somewhere, that there is a list of permissions that get added to files when they are created but I am having a great deal of trouble getting Google to distinguish between this case and other similar but unrelated cases.

Comment: Why do you think you need permissions to SQL Server data files? Only the SQL Server service account should be able to access those files.

Comment: What do you mean "an MDF file is created with some set or permissions", if you're using filelistonly - there isn't an actual restore happening. Was that just a typo?

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft I mean what I said, a BAK file is provided and an MDF is created in my SQLData location with the name of the database.

Comment: @mustaccio assume that there are reasons, maybe they are that I have a lot of other code that would need to be majorly refactored if I changed it to work they way you suggest.

Comment: 1) You can't restore a database using just filelistonly, so technically your question can't happen which is why I asked if it was a typo. 2) There is no way to change the way SQL Server ACLs files, I really do wonder what you'd need to do that TSQL or the engine can't do directly to the database files which you'd need extra permissions. Assuming you're using NTFS, you can set windows level inheritance.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` is creating this file? The create date matches when you ran the command? You've had someone with access to the file delete it, and running the command does make it appear again?

Comment: I am quite sure - but I don't care enough to get bogged down in a flame war about it so have removed the offensive line. Clearly, those of you whom I am beseeching for help know more about the intricacies of MSSQL server and perhaps would be kind enough to help

Comment: Why don't you restore the database to the location you're moving the MDF to in the first place?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Comment: @JamesRobinson - not trying to flame, just understand what you're seeing. As others have mentioned (and as I just double-checked myself), `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` does not appear to create a `.mdf` file (or, if it does, it removes it so quickly it doesn't register). And, if you're doing a regular `RESTORE`, you can use the `MOVE` option to put the files in their final destination directly, rather than having to move them there manually. Sean Gallardy, a SQL Server Premier Filed Engineer, has said that there's no option to change the default file permissions. Are we missing something?

Comment: Is it really the case that the permissions that MSSQL sets on files it creates is not configurable?

Answer (score 1):

By default `.mdf` file permissions are granted to Administrators Group and SQL Service Account when a database is restored.

Comment: This is precisely what I am observing, my question is do you know if there is a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I personally do *NOT* recommend this course of action, and there almost always is a better way of doing this, but you could technically use Powershell to do what Sean Gallardy mentioned:

> -Deattach the file from MS SQL Server
>
> -Verify it's de-attached
>
> -Change the NTFS permissions to grant move (delete/write) rights to the file.
>
> -Move it via powershell.
>
> -Re-attach it

It would be great if you could let the community know why you're stuck in this process.  Sometimes it's out of our hands, but if the team has better background info they might be able to help you in a slightly less risky and sensitive movement.

Moving MDF files is not one of the best practices to do.

In older versions I've seen database corruption from moving it from fast disks to slow disks.

You don't get any of the compression benefits.

Permissions sometimes have to be changed.

You can have unintended side effects such as Service Broker being disabled.

At a minimum check out using the [newer non depreciated](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/18/Dont-Use-sp_attach_db.aspx) commands.

Please just note if you perceive any sensitivity to your questions, the community is often just trying to help protect you from unintended consequences and/or needs more info.

Comment: Thanks for your offer of help Ali but this is not an answer to my question. If you know it is not configurable that would be a fine answer. However, the problem I have within the parameters I am able to solve it requires that I change the ownership of an MDF file. One option would be to run some code as the SQL server admin which does this, another option would be to have SQL server set different permissions when it creates MDF files, I am humbly asking if anyone knows how this is configured since the nuance is very difficult to explain to Google. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Ok so if I understand properly, the steps laid out above in the powershell section are not helpful because you explicitly need to run this from within SQL Server using T-SQL, and even Powershell from SQL Server is not going to be an option in this case.  Is that correct?  If so, you're really reaching some hard limits.  SQL Server is largely limited to xp_cmdshell and Powershell in regards to interfacing with the OS. Taking ownership or change file permissions from within SQL Server, which doesn't require powershell or xp_cmdshell isnt a feature. We cant even use PS as the SQL user in a job?

Comment: @JamesRobinson sorry forgot to tag you in my follow up question, wanted to make sure I clearly understood the constraints you are facing.

Comment: Hi Ali, I'm not trying to "change the permissions" so much as "change what permissions are set when creating a file". This is the nuance I can't explain to google.

Comment: ah gotcha thank you for the clarification @JamesRobinson.  RDFozz's answer as you noted gave you what is set.  The 'cleanest' way I could think to do this without a feature request to Microsoft (probably will be rejected) is to have a powershell script that monitors jobs if you have some critical jobs, perhaps disable the ones that aren't running, wait for the running ones to stop, then shut down the sql agent, change permissions, restart agent, enable jobs.  This is assuming you might have jobs you need to gracefully watch and if they run long, you're ok with other jobs being blocked.

Comment: If you have short jobs you don't mind running which you need, keep them going if you'd like.  This is hacky I agree, but I had to execute something similar (without changing the service agent user) to fail over EtL servers.  This is assuming jobs stop when the agent is stopped.  I know it's responsible for the scheduling of jobs but it might let running ones finish when it stops.  Not sure, needs testing. What do you think of this?

Comment: Using the command `exec xp_cmdshell 'icacls "MDF_LOCATION" /grant "DOMAIN\USER:F"'` I am able to change the permissions. I hate this solution since it requires me to leave xp_cmdshell available which seems like a substantial security vulnerability.

Comment: That would do the same thing but instead of using powershell it's using xp_cmdshell.  Have you considered using 'powershell' in a job and just executing the job?  That way you don't have to use xp_cmdshell which is an auditing nightmare and as you noted, potential security risk.

Comment: How is PowerShell any less insecure?

Comment: xp_cmdshell is going to run under the sql service account as only sysadmin members can use it.  This gives any SQL Admin group member the same rights as the SQL Service Account for Windows. 
 

Powershell can be called directly from a job under the drop down in the step and you can select 'powershell' from the list as opposed to calling a system extended stored procedure.  This makes it run under the sql agent account instead, and lets you use a proxy account as well.

Auditors also don't often ask about powershell, they will almost always ask about xp_cmdshell.